# How do I set app setting value using Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Wondering if it's possible for an Azure Function to set a value of an app setting.
For example whilst developing locally or in production one can read custom settings by binding it to a class

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<SomeSettingClass>()
                .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
                {                        configuration.GetSection(nameof(SomeSettingClass)).Bind(settings);
                });
```

and obviously use the settings at the main function method. However, is it possible to set a value and persist it for the next run?

Answer (score 0):

There many solutions to this, Azure has [Azure app configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview). it basically has all the plumbing and provides the appropriate configuration sources and providers to plugin into the `ConfigurationRoot`. This enables you use use the `IOptionsMonitor` feature to get real-time updates of configuration changes. Also there should be away to programmatically update it, however I have never tried it.

However, I find that service completely overpriced and clunky for what it is.

On that note, if you are handy with a bit of code, you could create your own `ConfigurationSource` and `ConfigurationProvider` to point to anywhere you like, for instance a CosmosDb container and do exactly the same thing. You could even use a trigger and signalR to publish those changes to any listening `ConfigurationSource`.

There are also various ways you can update a functions or apps configuration at runtime through the CLI etc (I am not sure if there C# management libraries for this, though I guess there is somewhere). However, they will not be real-time and have no inbuilt way of notifying as far as I know.

Which leaves you with the option of just doing a real time look up on a datastore `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. This way you can update and query at your own will, and will persist naturally.